# Tomcat Server ports in use...what to do now

Tags: java, node.js, tomcat, ports

I found the message telling me that the ports required by Tomcat are already in use.

```
netstat -an|grep 8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN     
netstat -an|grep 8005
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN
```

So,I created the file `tcp6.js` using `Node.js` and bound it to `9000`:

```
 var net=require('net');
 var chat=net.createServer();
 chat.on('connection',function(client){
    client.write('Die');
    client.end();
 });

 chat.listen(9000);
```

I logged out and logged back in.
But the netstat still shows tcp6 bound to 8080 and 8005.
These are the results of

```
ps aux | grep tomcat

tomcat7   2862  0.1  1.4 1960116 106080 ?      Sl   Mar19   1:46 /usr/lib/jvm/default-  
java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -  
Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC - 
Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -
Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat7/endorsed -classpath 
/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -
Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7 -
Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

anr      18444  0.0  0.0  13636   940 pts/2    S+   11:46   0:00 grep --colour=auto 
tomcat
```

Error printed in Eclipse Console:

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false],  
isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], 
isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false],   
isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], 
isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], 
isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], 
isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8180"] 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1678 ms
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.35
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8180"]
org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2199 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to tomcat home -> conf

There is a file called server.xml, in that search for 8080 and replace it with 8180 and restart the tomcat.

Comment: changed it to use the ports 8180 and 8105.The server started and the console had some errors,check the updated question please and tell me how to get rid of these errors

Comment: As per the console output I don't find any error. Everything is working fine only.

Answer (score 0):

In your tomcat installation directory find server.xml and change port their.

Answer (score 0):

You can do things depending on situation

**1) If you are running tomcat within eclipse do this ::**

Go to Servers tab, if not visible then go to menu bar window->show view-> Servers
Then **Double click** on the server you have created(***if not then create one***) on the right side you will see port numbers 8080, 8009,8005 change all of them to anything above 9000 like 9001, 9002 ,9003.
**Ctrl + save**
Restart your server it will run now

**2) If you are running Tomcat with out Eclipse i.e tomcat as a Service**
***(do this when you have shut down tomcat)***
Go to Tomcat installation directory

go to conf-> and open servers.xml with notepad, now find and replace 8080,8009,8005 with 9001,9002,9003 or any port above 9000,
do **Ctrl+save**

Restart tomcat as Service

what you just did is you changed the default port numbers that tomcat runs on !!! :)